# Issue with django filters by DateTime filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-filters

I have a django application with API. I created many queries something like :

```
class ShellMessageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    created = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="created",lookup_type="gte")

    class Meta:
        model = Server
        fields = ['created']


class ServersDateList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ServerSerializer
    queryset = Server.objects.all()
    filter_class = ShellMessageFilter
```

Which from URL get Date stamp and filtering it. 
But for now I need to create new filter which showing servers model which was update for the last two hour.
How I can do this?

I'll try something like this, but filter is broken and it showing all items :

```
class ShellMessageFilter2Hour(django_filters.FilterSet):

    import datetime

#    lastTwoHourDateTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
#    last_update = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name=str(lastTwoHourDateTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')),lookup_type="gte")

#    last_update2 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes = 10)
#    last_update = last_update2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d+%H:%M')

    last_update = django_filters.DateTimeFilter("2016-04-23T15:31:50")
    created = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="last_update",lookup_type="gte")

    class Meta:
        model = Server
        fields = ['last_update']


class ServersDate2HourList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ServerSerializer
    queryset = Server.objects.all()
    filter_class = ShellMessageFilter2Hour
```

Please help, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

In such a case [MethodFilter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html#methodfilter) is your friend and will enable you to use one filter class for your view.

You can implement like so:

```
class ShellMessageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def updates_in_last_two_hours(self, value):
        # You can toggle the value between True and False
        if value == 'true':
             right_now = datetime.datetime.now()
             last_two_hours = right_now - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
             return self.filter(created__gte=last_two_hours)
        else:
            return self.filter()
    created = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="created",lookup_type="gte")
    updated_last_two_hours = django_filters.MethodFilter(
        action=updates_in_last_two_hours)

class Meta:
    model = Server
    fields = ['created', 'updated_last_two_hours']
```

You can then use the updated_last_two_hours in the view like this ?updated_last_two_hours=true